# Arduino Detect something is connected to relay

Tags: arduino, pcb-design, adc, dc, coil

I have a diesel generator controlled using arduino, 8-ch relay board and it works great but sometimes during monthly maintenance workers unplug start/stop contactor coil wires from the arduino relay board causing the generator not be operated automatically, so i'm thinking of a way to monitor if start and stop contactor coils are connected to arduino relay board or not.

I came up with the following circuit, to use a voltage divider using the contactor coil with known value resistor and the resulting voltage will indicate a connected contactor coil or not:
[image: Relay Control]

This is the High power relay used to start and stop the generator, and i'm using arduino relay board to control this relay
[image: High power relay]

My question is aside from the coding part as I will be monitoring analog reading on A0 pin if value less than 2.5v then coil is connected else not connected.

will this circuit works or it could affect my arduino?

Comment: why don't you already monitor if the generator is actually running? ... there can be other failures, besides an non-operational relay

Comment: I'm already monitoring generator run using dynamo signal and other failures like low oil , high temp , etc.. , but would like to detect when someone disconnects the cables.

Comment: You might want to fix up your schematic so it is more readable- convention is to use a T symbol with the voltage to denote a power rail. You might want to ad a 100nF cap on the adc input and some protection.

Comment: why do the workers disconnect the wires?

Comment: Add reconnecting wires to the maintenance schedule.

Comment: @Kartman I added R3 after frying 2 arduino boards

Comment: remove R2, R3 and D3 .... insert a voltage divider between transistor collector and ground ... make sure that the voltage divider resistance is high enough so that the relay does not activate ... the voltage divider could have its own transistor, which could be activated briefly just to read continuity through the relay coil

Comment: @jsotola They say afraid of automatic start during maintenance

Comment: @BrianDrummond if I was able to log the action of disconnection, will be able to charge whomever responsible for the maintenance at that time, thus preventing future problems + less item from check list

Comment: @AmrSohil `They say afraid of automatic start during maintenance` .... then you have an improper, unsafe system ... the main run circuit on the generator should have a kill switch that can be locked out and tagged so that the generator does not start accidentally .... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockout%E2%80%93tagout

Comment: @jsotola I think the issue is not related to the controller, the problem is with old people mentality refusing the change and upgrade
take a look at the final product: [link] (https://scontent-hbe1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/98190457_1286990814837613_1147347646373953536_o.jpg?_nc_cat=104&ccb=3&_nc_sid=8bfeb9&_nc_ohc=JumyxOQf7QsAX9sfR7l&_nc_ht=scontent-hbe1-1.xx&oh=2ac5226151d34595c8b57e1445fde869&oe=60644EDF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, but there's details is in your drawing that make it unclear. Rather than dive into that, have a look here: ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgoqoQFMBaMMAKABcQ8rs1wwUQPKlQhMw0UpNJ4MAFjCFI2QuGhop0wgQwowxRnmRUAJnQBmAQwCuAGzYswGQ0JBpnvBcPBQ1IBimh5YjxsYkIwBC0MJTxGZh9IJDB4eASBNBZjVzxDFFkqFEjXfNcQU0tbewAnKEFeWXcvZLgWAHc%20dJ0OwUhZKBYAc27sBAFmAWVDYTbh5WHR-vauOqoGlcXuzAne1y7IBycQBpFFClk%20z1qIVAS4ZkhiWTIwbD0EBAJCbASklLg01z7drnXJ5I7LFBgoFHNaQvog4rTYFrPQCBGXaHHcDENEonH9LIIuEwwyo0rlax2FgAZ3BBXwdNcUNqlhs1LoM24vAYaxc%20wASkyLvxsWMRV4SuLajAEDMFEd5QweAqVPsavL5Cplprarh4CwADJ%20Xnc5Z8lkWNl0aj7IZEkpEopInrC7YXU7QlxuI7-b2Y30M-InZ1B8CndEembE8ZCxEbYl5ApFRPxrrewoqP1R5MMjNx6EoHKA5w7LPtXB9b0V-Mzaspwu5Eqe0slOt7KNgmPVmMCvzKnUMQjw%20US7jQb5eGVywsqwQLHWehaXEZokczbXy7XLaFbqhKtHbliTPsHvdDxnTLIblT8Qw6gQUyq1ubLpeRoA))

[image]

Like yours, this circuit uses a low sensing current to detect whether there's a low impedance (that is, relay plugged in) or not. The current is low enough that it can't pull in the relay; when the relay is plugged in the coil resistance is low enough to resolve a valid low. The sensing is disconnected when the relay is on.

Basically,

- Relay is plugged in, sense is close to zero
- Relay not plugged in, sense is 5V.

The Arduino should be able to read that no problem.

Comment: Actually flipping the load to the common pin has fixed my issue protecting the arduino from the higher voltages, Thanks for the correction and clarification :)